# Unable to locate english.txt file when trying to install Python Bitcoin module

Tags: python-2.7, bitcoin

When I try and import pybitcointools using "from bitcoin import *" from (https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) I get the following error, indicating the "english.txt" file is missing from one of the installation directories. How do I fix this?

> > > from bitcoin import *
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin-1.1.39-py2.7.egg/bitcoin/**init**.py", line 10, in 
> > >           from bitcoin.mnemonic import *
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin-1.1.39-py2.7.egg/bitcoin/mnemonic.py", line 7, in 
> > >           wordlist_english=list(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**)),'english.txt'),'r'))
> > >       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin-1.1.39-py2.7.egg/bitcoin/english.txt'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing a Bitcoin module in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562062/importing-a-bitcoin-module-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

This is related to a `pybitcointools` bug where the Pypi bitcoin .tar did not include the newly referenced `english.txt` file. This has since been fixed in v1.1.42.

The issue is described here:
https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/issues/138

To fix your installation, you can reinstall `pybitcointools` from [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitcoin) or run `pip install --upgrade pybitcointools`